# How tochange the permission of file on terminal?

Tags: 14.04, boot, permissions, 15.04

I tried to boot with Ubuntu LiveUSB and copy my important data to some external media.But permission denied shows,so how to change the permission?

Comment: What command did you use ?

Comment: I don't know? I  booted from another OS

Comment: try [this](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-need-permission-to-copy-files-in-ubuntu-live-cd.920078/) if useful =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [12.04 run from cd, cannot copy files from mounted disk](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159804/12-04-run-from-cd-cannot-copy-files-from-mounted-disk)

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change File/Fodder permissions by Opening up a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and typing in

This command will change all sub directory’s and files to read and right to every one.

```
sudo chmod ugo+wrx /media/external -Rf
```

Or you can run `sudo nautilus` in Terminal this will run nautilus with full rights so you won't have any permission errors when copying files and fodders to an external media.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy your important data open the file browser (`nautilus`) as root :

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute :

```
sudo apt-get install gksudo
```

When the installation is done :

```
gksudo dbus-launch nautilus
```

Copy your files ...

Comment: There is no need to install anything for that task. `sudo -H nautilus` will do.

Comment: @Pilot6 http://askubuntu.com/a/11766/338915